# How to specify glue version 3.0 for an AWS crawler with boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue, glue-crawler

I have an existing AWS glue crawler with a glue connector to a MySQL database that runs successfully. I need to move it to glue v3 so that it uses an updated MySQL JDBC driver (Glue 2.0 jobs use MySQL JDBC driver version 5.1 but AWS Glue 3.0 use MySQL JDBC driver 8.0.23). The crawler is created/updated with boto3's glue_client.update_crawler. The crawler is set to use a JDBC glue connector that is also created with boto3 and also does not have a glue_version parameter.

The documentation on boto3's glue client crawler functions, https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.update_crawler, does not include an option for GlueVersion. I don't see any relevant options in the console either. The crawler configuration has a version but I don't think it's the glue version and it errors out when I set it to 3.0. I'm not sure if there is maybe a default setting for glue version somewhere that crawlers use?

Currently I am using:

```html
glue_client = boto3.client('glue',region_name=region)
configuration= {"Version": 1.0,"Grouping": {"TableGroupingPolicy": "CombineCompatibleSchemas" }}

response = glue_client.update_crawler(
            Name= crawler_name,
            Role= glue_role_arn,
            DatabaseName=str(crawler_details['DatabaseName']) + '-' + str(env_suffix),
            Description=crawler_details['description'],
            Targets=targets,
            TablePrefix=crawler_details['TablePrefix'],
            Schedule=crawler_details['Schedule'],
            SchemaChangePolicy= crawler_details['SchemaChangePolicy'],
            Configuration=configuration
        )
```

How do I set a glue crawler to use GlueVersion = 3.0 using boto3?

Answer (score 0):

A Glue Crawler does not have a version, Glue Jobs have. You need to select the correct connection in the `target` property, so that you are able to connect to a newer version.

Comment: The connection is created using boto3 and the docs don't have a glue_version parameter for connection either, https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.update_connection.

The crawler itself doesn't have a glue version, but when the crawler is run it uses a version of glue from ... somewhere. AWS support - "I’ve checked your crawler and found that the Glue job is using Glue version 2.0... When I ran a new crawler with Glue version 3 it gave me the intended results "

Comment: Glue version is not a parameter of the crawler or connection boto3 create/update functions, but when a crawler is run it uses a version of glue (AWS confirmed this). I don't know where to set this property as neither the crawler nor connection boto3 functions have the option.

Thanks for any assistance.